# Presto window function- problem with date

Tags: sql, window-functions, presto

I have the following code in presto:

```
select distinct date_of_birth, substr(trim(tax_id), -4) as last_4, c_id ,  count(*) as cnt 
from schema.table
where tax_id not in ('', ' ')
and length (cast(date_of_birth as varchar)) > 0
group by c_id, date_of_birth , substr(trim(tax_id),-4)
order by cnt desc
```

this gives a result like this:

| date_of_birth | last_4 | c_id | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1878-09-31 | 1234 | xx-345 | 120 |
| 1889-02-22 | 4321 | yy-332 | 43 |
| 1899-03-13 | 5678 | ss-123 | 11 |

however Now I am trying to run a window function based on this result and get something like this and sort it on each week or month:

| date_ week | sum | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1878-09-31 | 100 | 3% |
| 1878-10-06 | 120 | 3.5% |
| 1878-10-11 | 140 | 3.6% |

percentage is relative to sum of all cnt in the previous table.
sum is the total of the week, for each 7 days.

here is my code so far, but it is not working, could you tell me what is wrong here?

```
 with cte as (
    select distinct date_of_birth as dob, substr(trim(tax_id), -4) as last_4, count(*) as cnt 
    from schema.table
    where tax_id not in ('', ' ')
    and length (cast(date_of_birth as varchar)) > 0
    group by date_of_birth , substr(trim(tax_id),-4)),
select date_trunc('week', yr) as yr, sum(cnt) over (group by dob rows between 5 preceeding and current row),
from cte 
order by yr;
```

It was not working so I could not move to finding percentage.

Comment: Your select is using `yr` while this column is not present in the `cte`

Comment: I see the mistake there, but still when I change the yr with dob in date_trunc it did not help much.

Comment: Query failed (#20220602_140029_00748_58qx8): line 3:16: mismatched input '.'. Expecting: ')', ',', 'AS', 'CROSS', 'EXCEPT', 'FULL', 'GROUP', 'HAVING', 'INNER', 'INTERSECT', 'JOIN', 'LEFT', 'LIMIT', 'NATURAL', 'ORDER', 'RIGHT', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'UNION', 'WHERE', <identifier>

Comment: Please add sample data (working with provided queries) and desired output .